# How do I extract data from the nested json using spark DS?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark DS with the below structure, I want to flatten each and extract all the columns. I tried `get_json_object` like below but it isn't working.

```
root
  |-- data: struct (nullable = true)
  |    |-- Level: long (nullable = true)
  |    |-- activityName: string (nullable = true)
  |    |-- activityRunId: string (nullable = true)
  |    |-- activityType: string (nullable = true)
  |    |-- category: string (nullable = true) 
  |    |-- correlationId: string (nullable = true)
  |    |-- effectiveIntegrationRuntime: string (nullable = true)
  |    |-- end: string (nullable = true)
  |    |-- level: string (nullable = true)
  |    |-- location: string (nullable = true)
  |    |-- operationName: string (nullable = true)
  |    |-- pipelineName: string (nullable = true)
  |    |-- pipelineRunId: string (nullable = true)
  |    |-- properties: struct (nullable = true)
  |    |    |-- Annotations: array (nullable = true)
  |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
  |    |    |-- Error: struct (nullable = true)
  |    |    |    |-- errorCode: string (nullable = true)


val DS = logDS.select(get_json_object($"data", "$.Level").alias("level"))
```

Requirement is I want to extract as separate columns

Comment: what do you mean by extract? do you mean you want them in separate columns? if so just use .* notation

Comment: yes want them as a separate columns, so that I can store them in any DB.

Comment: just do `val DS = logDS.select($"data.*")` and see if it resolves

Comment: cool it works but I also want to extract the column "errorcode" which is nested one level further

Comment: you can repeat the above step on DS again. hope it helps. try it and if still confusion let me know

Comment: Its working, Please write this as a solution. I will mark it as answer. Great Thanks !

Comment: I am marking it as duplicate instead as there are a lot of them :) thanks @prady